# Corp-to-Corp to FTE w/ Range Request?

Tags: salary, contractors

Currently, I work for a client as a Corp-to-Corp (C2C) contractor.

I'm discussing an FTE offer with another company. The company is waiting for me to give them a salary $ number - as part of the negotiation process.

A few, 10+ year consultants whom I know, mentioned that the following formulas are rough estimates of how to convert C2C hourly rate to an FTE salary.

```
FTE annual salary = (50 * corp_to_corp_hr_rate * 40) * .65
```

Example:

For a C2C contractor making $100 per hour, the FTE annual salary would be:

```
= (50 * $100 * 40) * .65
= $130,000
```

So, assuming I make $100, I would ask for $130,000 a year.

However, is it reasonable for me to ask the company what the range of software developers' salaries is? I ask because, not only to maximize my salary, but to be aware of expectations and future growth.

If it is reasonable, what's the recommended way to ask for it?

Comment: Is this US based?

Comment: Define FTE for those who don't know that abbreviation...

Comment: Usual rule: the first side to name a number in salary negotiations loses. Remember that whatever number you say will be an *upper* bound on what you will be offered.

Comment: Use Glassdoor to get a range.

Comment: VTC unclear. What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

It is always reasonable to ask what starting salary is typical. They may or may not answer.

Answer (score 1):

> However, is it reasonable for me to ask the company what the range of
>   software developers' salaries is? I ask because, not only to maximize
>   my salary, but to be aware of expectations and future growth.
>
> If it is reasonable, what's the recommended way to ask for it?

It's reasonable to ask, but I believe it weakens your negotiations. You are basically signalling that you don't know what you are worth.

Do your research. Look for jobs with your experience level and similar to the developer job as you understand it, and find some that indicate a salary level. Read on Glassdoor, PayScale, and others.

Then decide what you need to receive to accept a job and what you want to shoot for.

That way, you'll be in a stronger bargaining position.